# C# WPF WebBrowser - how to pass an array to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple markers to a google map. The data comes from C# WPF.

Here is the C# code:

```
private void Button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int[] lat = { 10, 30, 50, 70 };
    int[] lon = { 10, 30, 50, 70 };

    webBrowser1.InvokeScript("addMarker", new object[] { lat, lon });
}
```

Here is the javascript function embedded in a local html file:

```
function addMarker(Lat,Long) {
    for (var i=0;i<Lat.length; i++){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[i],Long[i]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Hello World!',
            map: map
        });
    }
    } // end of addMarker
```

When I compiled this program with VS 2015 and clicked the button to invoke this js script, I always got an error message telling me that a function is expected in this line right after 'var'

```
for (var i=0;i<Lat.length; i++){
```

The exception report by VS is like this:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101
and the location of the exception is right here:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("addMarker", new object[] { lat, lon });
```

I am very new to Javascript programming. Please help.

Comment: remove the "var" from the for, it's not needed.

Comment: Following your suggestion, the error is still there. But this time the location of error is moved to the left side of the '('. for (i=0; i<Lat.length; i++){

Comment: Check the object that's being sent to the function. I don't think it's formatted the way your loop wants to execute. Log the `Lat` and `Log` to the console.

Comment: the type of Lat in JS is shown as 'unknown' with this line: alert(typeof(Lat)); How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know its not possible to pass an array directly.

You should pass it as a JSON-string. (I am using [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) via NuGet!)

```
guiWebbrowser.InvokeScript("addMarker", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
         {
            Lat = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 },
            Long = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 }
         }));
```

Your JS-function should look like this:

```
function addMarker(jsonArg) {
   var args = JSON.parse(jsonArg);
   for (var i = 0; i < args.Lat.length; i++) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(args.Lat[i], args.Long[i]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latLng,
         title: 'Hello World!',
         map: map
      });
   }
} // end of addMarker
```

You may get this error message: `JSON is undefined`.

See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287896/3631348

You should call this function anywhere in your app:

```
public void ModifyBrowserEmulation(int version = 11001)
{
   // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287896/3631348 --> edit your application name ! or get it via Reflection !

   var appExe = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appExe, version, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appExe.Replace(".exe", ".vshost.exe"), version, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appExe, version, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appExe.Replace(".exe", ".vshost.exe"), version, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
```

Another useful post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728506/3631348 how to write to the console from your JS code.

Comment: Although this is a so much delayed answer, it is correct. Thanks.